# Error when binding date parameter to prepared statement -- Using PHP PDO/ODBC with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have a pdo connection with ODBC (v2000.86.359.00) connecting to an SQL Server (v8.00.2039 SP4 Standard Edition) database.

This works:

```
$id = 486;
$duedate = 'June 27, 2012';
$query ="INSERT into AssetHistory (AssetID, DateDue) Values($id, $duedate);";                   
$noParams = $db->exec($query);
$db->query($query);
```

But if I try to use a prepared statement like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT into AssetHistory 
    (AssetID, DateDue)
    Values(:id, :duedate);';                

$input = array(':id'=>486, ':duedate'=>'June 27, 2012');
$smt = $db->prepare($sql);
$smt->execute($input);
```

I get this error (from $smt->errorInfo()):

```
 "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)"
```

I've tried:
1) Enclosing :duedate in single quotes
2) Binding date to unix timestamp integer
3) Binding :duedate to php DateTime object
4) Inserting just $duedate into the sql statement before preparing

At this point I might be stuck using the $db->query method and sanitizing inputs as best I can, but I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Using PHP 5.38 on a Windows Server 2003 box.

*Updates:*
I've removed some of the variables from a previous version of this question. The error message has changed, but the end result is the same.

I've also tried manually binding the parameters like so:

```
$smt->bindValue(':id', 486, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$smt->bindValue(':duedate', 'June 27, 2012', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Along with adding the convert function to the sql like so:

```
$sql = 'INSERT into AssetHistory 
   (AssetID, DateDue)
Values(:id, convert(datetime,:duedate, 100));';
```

Which returns:
    "COUNT field incorrect or syntax error "

And I've noticed that SQL Server doesn't really [play nice](http://mysql.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-datetime-value-to-a-unix-timestamp.html) with unix timestamps...

Comment: String with a formatted date -- I've tried 'June 27, 2012' and '2012-06-27 00:00.000'

Comment: Well, have you tried long-form: `$smt->bindValue(':duedate',$duedate,PDO::PARAM_INT);`? Or, casting `$duedate=intval($duedate);`?

Comment: Thanks to all your suggestions I've updated the question. At this point I've tried everything that has been suggested without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved this by downloading and installing both the [sqlsrv php drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (I used version 2.0) and the [SQL Server 2008 Native Client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16177#SNAC).

With a little tweak to the $dsn parameter, the rest of the code works like magic -- no binding, converting or casting required.

I ended up only using the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll`, but make sure you select the correct thread-safe/ non-thread safe version of the driver, as the wrong dll in you php.ini will crash your server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

```
 $phpdate = strtotime( $duedate);
```

You could also try using [SQL's `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in your statement

```
 convert(datetime, :duedate, 100)
```

The datatype in SQL is datetime, correct?

OR try:

```
array(':id'=>486, ':borrower'=> 'name', ':loaner'=>'KOPERW', ':duedate'=>strtotime($duedate),

array(':id'=>486, ':borrower'=> 'name', ':loaner'=>'KOPERW', ':duedate"=>$duedate),"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```

Comment: At this point I'm using an string literal in the array: `$input = array(':id'=>486, ':borrower'=> 'JOHNSMITH', ':loaner'=>'KOPERW',':duedate'=>'June 27, 2012', ':loaneragain'=>'KOPERW' );`

Comment: Before that I tried `$duedate = strtotime('June 27, 2012');` which returned an integer and the same error.

Comment: And yes, the datatype in SQL is datetime.

Answer (score 0):

"COUNT field incorrect or syntax error" can occur if you set up a parameterized query but then fail to pass the required number of parameters in the parameters list.

Your code looks ok on that front, however.