# PHP PDO bindValue fails on ODBC to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I want to bind Values to a SQL Statement using a PDO connection to an SQL Server via ODBC.

If I execute the statement without a parameter I get a result but if I want to bind a parameter to that sql I get a "Function sequence error" thrown back.

```
$fromDate = strval(date('Y-d-m'))." 00:00:00.000";

//works
$sql = "SELECT a.FromDate FROM Absence a WHERE a.FromDate > '".$fromDate."'";
$arrParams = [];
runStatement($sql, $arrParams);

//don't work
$sql = "SELECT a.FromDate FROM Absence a WHERE a.FromDate > :fromdate1";
$arrParams = [':fromdate1' => $fromDate];
runStatement($sql, $arrParams);

//thats how I bind the parameters

function runStatement($sql, $arrParams)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    foreach($arrParams as $key => $value)
    {
      $stmt -> bindValue($key, $value);
    }
    $stmt -> execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I tried to bind the values with bindParam() but the error remains the same. On Sqlite and Ingres Database the bindValue() works fine for me.
I am using PHP 8.x and SQL Server 2012. Installing the php drivers for SQL doesn't work here.

Edit: I could narrow down the error to the date type. Because in the where clause I want to compare two dates.
When I try other statements without dates as binded params the statement works fine.

So the comparison of the datetype is the error here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657548/function-sequence-error-sql-state-s1010-while-executing-a-prepared-statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213831/error-when-binding-date-parameter-to-prepared-statement-using-php-pdo-odbc-wi

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22function+sequence+error%22+prepared+statement+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried these before asking.

Comment: When someone tries something before asking, it is always mentioned in the question.

Comment: My personal experience with PHP, PHP Driver for SQLServer and date/time values is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276287/php7-3-sqlsrv-format-of-datetime-different-when-query-and-store/55286218#55286218).

Comment: Yes. I was about to say that MS SQL being extremely picky about date formats.

Comment: Even more picky than you think. Even PHP date strings formatted `y-d-m H-i-s.v` can get rejected by SQL Server depending on the connection's current `SET DATEFORMAT` option. To be setting-invariant it needs a `T` separator between the date and time portions, `y-d-m\TH-i-s.v`.

Comment: `Ymd` would be the obvious format to try, as that is the one that SQL Server supports. Using the `sqlsrv` might be a better option than PDO also.

Comment: Tried sqlsrv but somehow I couldn't managed to get it to work.
And yeah Ymd would be smarter but the comparison somehow just works when using Ydm